# redux state value returns undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I declare state via redux connect

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    singleBase: state.interaction.base
});

export default requiresLogin()(connect(mapStateToProps)(BasePage));
```

The state shows fine via console log `console.log(this.props.singleBase);`

```
id: "5b757e6743904228586a5a7f"
creatorId: "5b6e39ce08406602d0a9e125"
title: "tester"
currentUsers: 2
messages: 0
```

On the backend I have the following model:

```
const BaseSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  creatorId: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, required: true },
  title: { type: String, required: true },
  currentUsers: { type: Number, default: 0 },
  messages: { type: Number, default: 0 }
});
```

But when I try to console log the value of `currentUsers`: `console.log(this.props.singleBase.currentUsers);` I get the following error: `Cannot read property 'currentUsers' of undefined`.

I tried both setting the Schema to a pure number, e.g. 5, as well as as a text "5". Neither one works. What detail am I missing to be able to get the value of `currentUsers` ?

EDIT & SOLUTION:

```
const users =
    this.props.singleBase && this.props.singleBase.currentUsers !== undefined
    ? this.props.singleBase.currentUsers
    : 0;
return (
    <div>
      <h2>{users}</h2>
    </div>
);
```

Here we ensure that this.props.singleBase exists and is true, while I make sure that this.props.singleBase.currentUsers has a value that is not undefined. If both evaluates true I display this.props.singleBase.currentUsers. The point of this is that until the asynchronous action has completed the singleBase will be empty. Once filled with data, I can display the currentUsers value.

Comment: mapStateToProps looks valid. I assume you have some 'interaction' reducer for your store. Can you make sure that in the reducer you are properly handling schema object from backend? Particularly that you are returning new state.

Comment: else if (action.type === FETCH_SINGLE_BASE_SUCCESS) {
  return Object.assign({}, state, {
   base: action.base
  });
 } .. If it shows up correctly in a console.log I'd assume it is returning the new state correctly

Comment: when/where you're trying to log data? render/lifecycle

Comment: export class BasePage extends React.Component { 
  render() {
    console.log(this.props.singleBase.currentUser)
    return (...)
  }
}

in the same class I have a ComponentDidMount dispatch which fetches the above specific base data. Is it possible that it returns undefined because it is technically not done yet (promise)? If so, why does it successfully console log ?

Comment: @Helle Please [edit] your post to include the additional code. This site does not allow code formatting in comments. Also please provide a [mcve] that recreates the problem you are asking about.

Answer (score 1):

You are most probably getting this data asynchronously, this is why you are getting this error. Before logging `this.props.singleBase` you should see an `undefined` in the console. This does not fire an error but if you try to get some property of an undefined object you hit this error. Trying to log undefined objects is ok, but trying to log a property where this object is undefined is not since at this time that object is `undefined`.

You can put a condition before your log:

```
this.props.singleBase && console.log(this.props.singleBase.currentUsers);
```

This is what will you do to render your items in the future instead of logging them. So, always remember, if you are doing an asynchronous job, there will be no data in the first render.

Comment: Should the component re-render once the data becomes available via props ?

Comment: Of course. When a component gets a new prop it rerenders.

Comment: Then I don't get why it doesn't automatically re-render once the data becomes available

Comment: I didn't understand. As I said in my previous comment, it rerenders automatically when data becomes available. This means your component gets a new prop. But, before it becomes available your object is undefined and you are trying to get a property from this undefined object. This causes the error.

Comment: You had it right. Just worked it into my own answer. Thanks, mate

Answer (score 1):

```
const users =
    this.props.singleBase && this.props.singleBase.currentUsers !== undefined
    ? this.props.singleBase.currentUsers
    : 0;
return (
    <div>
      <h2>{users}</h2>
    </div>
);
```

Here we ensure that `this.props.singleBase` exists and is `true`, while I make sure that `this.props.singleBase.currentUsers` has a value that is not undefined. If both evaluates true I display `this.props.singleBase.currentUsers`. The point of this is that until the asynchronous action has completed the singleBase will be empty. Once filled with data, I can display the currentUsers value.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

It might be happening because you're trying to `console.log` it before the current state is loaded. Try setting some flag like `loading=true` while you're getting your asynchronous data, and then change it to `false` after loading it.